# CSS. Не получается центрировать изображение

Tags: html, css

Почему не работает простое центрирование изображения через CSS?

```css
img.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="http://drobs.ru/opyat/8/peyzazh_priroda_holmy_derevya_zelen_tuman_rassvet_solnce_5576x3087.jpg" alt="Accenture" style="width:304px; margin: 0;">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у вас в теге `img` прописан инлайн стиль

```
style="width:304px; margin: 0;"
```

который более приоритетен, чем прописанные в css `margin-left: auto;` и `margin-right: auto;`, которые по вашему замыслу должны центрировать.
Инлайновые стили, то есть прописанные прямо в описании html элемента, самые приоритетные.

Уберите `margin:0` и все станет хорошо для центрирования по горизонтали.

Answer (score 0):

просто в стиле img напиши margin: 0 auto;